Does each tab in a Chrome extension create a new Service Worker instance?
Do multiple service workers run when a Chrome extension host app has multiple tabs and the popup page opens in a tab? What I mean by "host app" is at the bottom.
I'm working on a Chrome extension that opens a React-based UI in a sticky tab when the extension icon is clicked. I often have multiple tabs of the host app open simultaneously.
Recently, I've noticed occasional duplicate post requests being triggered from my extension, but the console logs show only a single request, which makes me suspect that this might be due to multiple service worker instances.
My question is:
If multiple tabs of the host app are open, will there be separate service worker instances running for each tab?
Could this be the reason for seeing duplicate post requests?
Is there a way to check if multiple service workers are active or if there’s any overlap between them?
I'm struggling to track down the cause of these occasional duplicate post, and any insights or debugging tips would be helpful.
Host app: I mean, the web app that I developed the chrome extension for that has a wild card specified in host_permissions. The extension intercepts some API calls from the web app and then processes those notifications itself by refetching and then posts a request to another server. It's this post request that is duplicating sometimes.
Addendum: I also added Chrome Notification to popup on a post request and I see duplicate notifications open up.

No, it doesn't, but Chrome duplicates its console output in every chrome-extension:// tab (or frame from web_accessible_resources).

Thanks, that helps. I also found that if I close the pinned React UI tab that I created on chrome.action.onClicked.addListener, the duplicate POSTs problem goes away. Not sure if this makes sense. Need more testing days to confirm.

doesn't React render twice during DEV in strictmode? do you have the same issue if you build and test?

I always build before reloading the extension. Now at least I know that the problem is related to opening the onclick UI in a pinned tab. I made it a regular popup window through manifest, and the problem went away. Somehow, a pinned tab creates another service worker although one can't make it out from the log.
